# Link 3rd party static libraries into static lib's test target result's undefined symbols error

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, static, xctest

I am working on a modularized project that is built up from modules that are static libraries. Each static library has an xctest test bundle. The project also has static 3rd party dependencies (e.g. Swinject)

Mach-O Type in the build settings of test targets is "Bundle". The 3rd party frameworks are added to the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" on the main target and also to the test bundle in our static lib, framework search paths are also set correctly on both.

However while the build is successful on the main target, when I try to run the tests it results the following compiler error:

*Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__T08Swinject9ContainerCMa", referenced from:
      __T08Swinject9ContainerCSgMa in MyClassTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*

So eventually in my understanding the 3rd party framework is linked to the test target in the same way as it is linked to the main target, yet building on test bundle is not working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your test target automatically links against your main target. But any other frameworks and libraries the test target references must be explicitly linked. They don't come along for free.